# SUM() on a form footer resulting in #Error

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I'm trying to display the sum of a field in a text box in the form footer.  The field is not calculated in any way.

Here are a couple of the things I've tried:

```
=Sum([txtWeldInches])
=Sum([WeldInches])
=Sum(CDbl([txtWeldInches]))
=Sum(CDbl([WeldInches]))
```

...well you get the idea.  Each iteration I've used results in the Text Box displaying #Error Without exception.

I've used similar constructs in different forms in the same project, so I'm not sure what the problem might be.

Has anyone run into this before?

EDIT:
I ended up writing a VBA routine to update the boxes when it was likely that they would be changed rather than trying to get a bound sum() function to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the field "WeldInches" existing in the data source for this form?
What datatype the field "WeldInches" is?

EDIT: I have looked at all your comments. If it doesn't work by databinding, try and use the unbounded way. At runtime, get the value of WeldInches using DSUM and set the footer textbox's value when the form loads.

Also, remember to update it at places where you think the SUM could change.

Comment: WeldInches is a numeric datatype (specifically a SQL Server float) and there are no nulls in the dataset.  It also definitely exists on the form.  It is what is populating txtWeldInches.

Comment: Try "=Sum(NZ([WeldInches], 0)).

Comment: I know that there are no nulls in the dataset for this to make a lick of difference but I tried it anyway and it still didn't work.  I'm starting to wonder if I shouldn't try and find a workaround.

Answer (score 6):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/199355

All of the domain functions are based on the same query (over the underlying recordset). If one of the bound functions on the form has a binding error, all of the functions on the form will return an error.

In other words, make sure all your footer controls are resolving properly and not hitting any nulls.

If you use a `SUM` or `AVG` then make sure you are also using the `Nz` function:

ControlSource = `=SUM(NZ([FIELD],0))`

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem as Rister.
The source of the form was an underlying query.
I had a bound text box named `txtQty` on this form. Its control source was `Qty` (based on the underlying query of the form).
I created an unbound text box and entered `=SUM([txtQty])` and received an error.
I tried various ways to find a solution and was very desperate.
Then I deleted the underlying query and created a new one using the same name and fields as before.
Then I entered `=SUM([Qty])` into the unbound text box on the form and voila, it worked. Note that I didn't enter the name of the bound text box (`txtQty`) into the expression, but its control source (`Qty`). I don't know why, but it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You want to sum by the name of the column in the record source: `SUM([WeldInches])`

Make sure there are no other textboxes with the name `WeldInches`.

Comment: There aren't any other controls that even come close.  The closest is the one that I'm trying to assign the value to and that's called txtSumWeldInches.

Comment: I have found since version 2000 that Access forms are unreliable when attempting to refer to the fields in the underlying recordset, and the solution is often to create a hidden textbox with the value you're trying to aggregate (assuming there's not already a control displaying that data). If you have a control called txtWeldInches, try making the ControlSource of txtSumWeldInches =Sum([txtWeldInches]).

Comment: This is actually what I tried first.  I was surprised when it gave me an error and I tried my luck with Google before posting here.

Answer (score 1):

I know you said "Form" but for those who have issues with the Sum formula in an Access "Report" the formula has to be in the Report Footer NOT the Page footer. Took me a while to figure it out as Access defaults to only showing the page footer.

Comment: Wow thanks, this took me way too long to figure out.. god I hate access

Answer (score 0):

None of the Sum() formulas will work in the text boxes that are copied from the Detail section into the form footer, even with the simplest of expressions, like:

=Sum([Hours])

The text boxes that use the Sum() formula in the form footer have to be individually added to the form footer from the Form Design menu instead of copied from the Detail section and modified to contain Sum() formulas.  This is a bug of Microsoft Access.  The version in my File / Account menu is, "Version 2108 (Build 14326.21018 Click-to-Run)".